# Built-in global storage in Apache HTTPD

Tags: c, apache

I'm developing apache httpd module. I have to deal with some global stats. I found Apache HTTPD provides a per-server, a per-directory and a per-request configuration. Is there any built-in global storage in Apache HTTPD?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _global storage_?

Answer (score 0):

In 2.4 you can use the services provided by mod_slotmem, as long as a cross-process provider like SHM is loaded.